# String function "CharAt" storing and displaying numeric values in "char"

Tags: java.util.scanner, charat, string-function

Ok guys so i'm using this string function "charAT" to store charater variable to store in char r. But we know user can input anything. When user enters a numeric value like 123 or 5 or anything charAt is storing that in char variable r. Exception should have come but it didn't. How is char variable able to hold a numeric value. How can i fix this? i want "r" to hold only char values and want the exception to occur if user inputs the numeric value.

```
package string;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example 
{

Scanner s1;
String str;
char r;

Example()
{
  s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
}

void display()
{
    while(true)
    {
    try {

    System.out.println("Please enter the grade");
    str = s1.nextLine();
    r = str.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("The grade is "+ r);
    break;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("you have entered an invalid input. Please try again \n");
    }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Example().display();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java the value of `String` and `char` can also accept numeric values. So if you enter 123 as input then the String will be "123" and the char will be `1`. If you only want to get alphabets as input then you can do it using the `hasNext` method in the `Scanner` class of Java. This will use a `Regular Expression` such as `[A-Za-z]` to make sure only alphabets can be given as input.

```
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the grade");
        while (!s1.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
            System.out.println("you have entered an invalid input. Please try again \n");
            s1.next();
        }
        str = s1.next();
        r = str.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("The grade is "+ r);
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("There was an exception \n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to test whether the character falls within a certain ASCII range:

```
ascii = (int) str.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
if ( ( ascii >= (int) 'a' ) && ( ascii <= (int) 'f' ) ) {
    // Valid!
} else {
    // Invalid!
}
```